# Get the count and values of a distinct order

Tags: r

I'm struggling with this problem and I don't know if there is a more elegant solution besides just looping down the column with a bunch of conditional logic built in. I have data that looks like so:

```
data.frame(user=c(rep("01",14),rep("02",6),rep("03",9)),time= c(1:14,1:6,1:9), 
           event = c(rep("a",3),"d",rep("a",1),rep("b",2),rep("a",2),rep("d",2),rep("a",3),
                     rep("b",2),rep("a",2),rep("c",2),rep("d",2),rep("b",5),rep("c",1),rep("b",1)))
```

For each `user`, I would like to get each change in `event` going down `time` and the number of the occurrences coming from the previous event. So that would look like this:

```
data.frame(user=c(rep("01",6),rep("02",2),rep("03",3)), 
           source=c("a","d","a","b","a","d", "b","a", "d","b","c"), 
           target=c("d","a","b","a","d","a", "a","c", "b","c","b"),
           source_cnt=c(3,1,1,2,2,2 ,2,2, 2,5,1))
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: For future reference, all those `rep` calls can be sandwiched into one call per vector.  e.g. `c(rep("a", 3), rep("b", 2), "c")` can be done more efficiently as  `rep(c("a", "b", "c"), 3:1)`

Comment: I might be dense at the moment, but I don't see how there are 3 counts of 'a' changing to 'd' for 'user' 01, which is what is in the first row of your intended output.

Comment: @shea Do think there should be 5? There should be 3 because I'm interested in each change in event, not *unique* changes.

Comment: @d.b, I didn't get enough sleep last night. I get it now. For each change combination, nsalas wanted the max count of the source event in the change. I thought nsalas was looking for the number of changes for each source / target combination. '... each change in event', sounds like counting changes. I suppose the problem could have been worded better. You picked it up though. I definitely need a nap.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
do.call(rbind, lapply(split(df, df$user), function(x){
    ev = rle(as.character(x$event))
    data.frame(user = x$user[1],
               source = head(ev$values, -1),
               target = ev$values[-1],
               source_cnt = head(ev$lengths, -1))
}))
#     user source target source_cnt
#01.1   01      a      d          3
#01.2   01      d      a          1
#01.3   01      a      b          1
#01.4   01      b      a          2
#01.5   01      a      d          2
#01.6   01      d      a          2
#02.1   02      b      a          2
#02.2   02      a      c          2
#03.1   03      d      b          2
#03.2   03      b      c          5
#03.3   03      c      b          1
```